# Function assigned to Vue.prototype returns unresolved Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js

## What I'm doing

I'm trying to assign an async function to call my API to Vue.prototype.API.
However, despite that the same function works when I declare them on methods property, it just doesn't work.

Functions assigned to Vue.prototype.API

```
async function API(config) {
  return await axios(config)
}
```

Returning value from Vue.prototype.API

```
{
    "_c": [],
    "_s": 0,
    "_d": false,
    "_h": 0,
    "_n": false
}
```

Expected response

```
{
        "data": {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 1,
            "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
            "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
        },
        "status": 200,
        "statusText": "OK",
        "headers": {
            "cache-control": "public, max-age=14400",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "expires": "Sat, 12 Jan 2019 20:07:37 GMT",
            "pragma": "no-cache"
        },
        "config": {
            "transformRequest": {},
            "transformResponse": {},
            "timeout": 0,
            "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
            "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            "maxContentLength": -1,
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
            },
            "method": "get",
            "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
        },
        "request": {}
    }
```

Comment: Please post the whole code that you run for the working and non-working cases

Comment: Are you using a transpiler and a minified promise library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be several things depending on where you're setting the function and how you're handling the return. The response that you're getting looks somewhat like an unresolved `Promise`. Are you making sure to resolve the network response before setting it in your `Vue.prototype`?

Comment: It was an unresolved promise.
It started working when I used async/await before doing stuff with the promise.